# Creating a column that assigns max value of set of rows by condition to all rows in that group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data    metadata
A         0
A         1
A         2
A         3
A         4
B         0
B         1
B         2
A         0
A         1
B         0
A         0
A         1
B         0
```

`df.data` contains two different categories, `A` and `B`. `df.metadata` stores a running count the number of times a category appears consecutively before the category changes. I want to create a column `consecutive_count` that assigns the max value of metadata per consecutive group to every row in that group. It should look like this:

```
data    metadata    consecutive_count
A         0              4
A         1              4
A         2              4
A         3              4
A         4              4
B         0              2
B         1              2
B         2              2
A         0              1
A         1              1
B         0              0
A         0              1
A         1              1
B         0              0
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**:
You may try transform `max` on groupby of each group of `data`

```
s = df.data.ne(df.data.shift()).cumsum()
df['consecutive_count'] = df.groupby(s).metadata.transform('max')

Out[96]:
   data  metadata  consecutive_count
0     A         0                  4
1     A         1                  4
2     A         2                  4
3     A         3                  4
4     A         4                  4
5     B         0                  2
6     B         1                  2
7     B         2                  2
8     A         0                  1
9     A         1                  1
10    B         0                  0
11    A         0                  1
12    A         1                  1
13    B         0                  0
```

---

**Method 2**:
Since `metadata` is sorted per group, you may reverse dataframe and do groupby `cummax`

```
s = df.data.ne(df.data.shift()).cumsum()
df['consecutive_count'] = df[::-1].groupby(s).metadata.cummax()

Out[101]:
   data  metadata  consecutive_count
0     A         0                  4
1     A         1                  4
2     A         2                  4
3     A         3                  4
4     A         4                  4
5     B         0                  2
6     B         1                  2
7     B         2                  2
8     A         0                  1
9     A         1                  1
10    B         0                  0
11    A         0                  1
12    A         1                  1
13    B         0                  0
```

Comment: `cummax` method is pretty nice